# How I can get the shortest distance from a line to an attractor in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I want to get the shortest distance from a line to an attractor/point node in Anylogic. In all the available references, I found the function to calculate point to point distance. Is there any function/suggested way to calculate a line to point distance in Anylogic? (Please let me know if my question is not clear enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best use a `Path` element from the "Space Markup" library, not a  `Line`.

This allows you to call `getNearestPoint` as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben! I will try this one.

Comment: Hi Ben! I have one additional question. I tried your method. You can see I need to put one point type "output". I am not sure, what point it is referring to. As I am giving my path markup & Xaxis, Yaxis values, can you please guide me what additional argument it is asking for? I am not getting the sense of Point out in the last part. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: not sure tbh, try experimenting a little yourself to figure it out :) Might not be possible after all since this "getNearestPoint" method is designed for the parent class of NetworkMarkupElements... You may have to resort coding this yourself

Comment: Thanks Ben! actually that problem was sorted out. For "type out" I referenced the endpoint of the path markup & it's working fine.